# jQuery .slideUp() effect running issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody tell me why the Effect is running so often is hovered. I mean you hover 3 times without to wait that the Effect is finished and than you can wait until the Effect has run 3 times.

```
   $(function() {
            $('#dropdown_nav li').find('.sub_nav').hide();
            $('#dropdown_nav li').hover(function() {

                $(this).find('.sub_nav').slideDown(300);
            }, function() {

                $(this).find('.sub_nav').delay(2000).slideUp(300);
            });
        });
```

Here can it be tested: http://jsfiddle.net/QTGvJ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.stop()` will clear the animation queues

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QTGvJ/2/)**</kbd>

```
$('#dropdown_nav li').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function() {
      $('.sub_nav', this).stop().slideToggle();
});
```

With delay for the mouseleave:

```
$('#dropdown_nav li').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ) {
    var delayTime = e.type=='mouseleave' ? 1000 : 0;
    $('.sub_nav', this).stop().delay( delayTime ).slideToggle();
});
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO 2 WITH DELAY](http://jsfiddle.net/QTGvJ/3/)**</kbd>

Find out more: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Is it normal that during slideUp to hover again breaks the effect and does not slideDown completly?

Comment: @user2036282 I edited my answer, refresh it and take a look at the demo

Comment: Thanks but you have removed .delay() and set .slideToggle(). I want to delay during slideUp

Comment: @user2036282 sorry, I missed that part, but it's really easy to play with that part using Ternary operator and the `e`vent listener, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/QTGvJ/3/